# Nginx - Reverse proxy to an already reverse proxied location or double reverse proxy?

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using nginx on centos 7.

I am reverse proxying a remote nodejs server on the same LAN to the nginx root / as per the below:

```
    location / {

    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.104:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

This works fine for serving my website - all external requests on port 80 are rewritten to use https which has been configured in nginx e.g nginx forwards any incoming http requests to https and deals with rewrites and forwarding so that the nodejs content is served over ssl even though ssl hasn't been configured within the node application.

e.g my site can be accessed at https://example.com

I now want to reverse proxy another nodejs app so that it appears at a location which is prefixed with https://example.com e.g: https://example.com/node2/

I've tried using the below config for the second node server...

```
    location /node2/ {

    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.100:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
    }
```

When I load the https://example.com/node2/ url, the html of the root page of the second node server is displayed but none of the css, js or images are loaded so the page doesn't look or work as it should and I see the following in the browser console...

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/node2/' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://192.168.1.100:3000/assets/graphics/logo.png'. This content
>   should also be served over HTTPS.

and

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED https://192.168.1.100:3000/assets/css/styles.min.css

for css and js assets... so it seems that no redirection is taking place for assets and also any links on the html page do not show the /node2/ suffix when hovered over or when clicked as the page tries to load the resource from https://example.com instead of https://example.com/node2/

Is it possible to actually do what I want in terms of reverse proxy two locations and can anyone point me in the right direction on how I can get this work as need?

Comment: The applicatoin running on 192.168.1.100 appears to be trying to load content using its IP address, not the URL it is hosted at. Take a look at the code for that application, and ensure it is loading content using relative paths.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason it is using an ip address is because it's running on another machine on my lan - my router forwards https traffic to the centos server running nginx - nginx then reverse proxies its / to another machine on my lan running a node.js server (which works fine) - the problem is that when I then try to reverse proxy a second node.js server app running on yet another host on my lan using a location add-on e.g site/node2app. its assets and links aren't proxyed with the correct url - they point to the first reversed proxyed url and not the extended one.. hope that makes sense

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I found that the node app I was trying to proxy to the /node2/ location uses webpack and babel internally so I will need to edit it to use the 'file-loader' module so that assets are loaded correctly within the app rather than me trying to use nginx to deal with this - so you did point me in the right direction - if you put your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct - thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application being loaded is set up to load assets from the server root, not with server root + /node2/